# Jquery Codrops Calendario - Change default date format from MM-DD-YYYY to DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to customize this nice calendar from Codrops [Calendario](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/11/27/calendario-a-flexible-calendar-plugin/) wich by default uses MM-DD-YYYY to make things work

```
caldata format:
    {
        'MM-DD-YYYY' : 'HTML Content',
        'MM-DD-YYYY' : 'HTML Content',
        'MM-DD-YYYY' : 'HTML Content'
        ...
    }
```

and then uses the options from this object literal to create variables today, month, year

```
        this.today = new Date();
        this.month = ( isNaN( this.options.month ) || this.options.month == null) ? this.today.getMonth() : this.options.month - 1;
        this.year = ( isNaN( this.options.year ) || this.options.year == null) ? this.today.getFullYear() : this.options.year;
        this.caldata = this.options.caldata || {};
        this._generateTemplate();
        this._initEvents();
```

My question is, how (if possible) should I transform date format from MM-DD-YYYY to my usual DD-MM-YYYY?

Thanks!

Comment: In the demos I don’t see that calendar display a “full” date anywhere – so is your question about the _input_ format? If so, why mess with that? Just format your _input_ data that you feed to the calendar in the expected format in the first place.

Comment: yes, it's about input format. In my country we always use dates as dd-mm-yyyy, the goal is to avoid having events not showing up because of our lack of attention when adding events this callendar

Comment: Well, if that script does not offer customization of the input format as an option, then you would have to either meddle with the plugin code itself, or write your own “pre-parser” for the options that translates from format `a` to format `b` before passing the data to the calendar itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try change this line 163 of `jquery.calendario.js`:

```
var strdate = ( this.month + 1 < 10 ? '0' + ( this.month + 1 ) : this.month + 1 ) + '-' + ( day < 10 ? '0' + day : day ) + '-' + this.year
```

for this one:

```
var strdate = (day < 10 ? '0' + day : day) + '-' + ( this.month + 1 < 10 ? '0' + ( this.month + 1 ) : this.month + 1 ) + '-' + this.year,
```

and on the `date.js` you can set this:

```
var codropsEvents = {
    '23-05-2015' : '<span>Gamma Gallery: A Responsive Image Gallery Experiment</span>'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Script does offer a way to change the format, but you have to use https://github.com/deviprsd21/Calendario (this repo maintains calendario after taking permission from codrops).

```
$("#calendar").calendario({
    format: 'MM-DD-YYYY' //Could be DD-MM-YYYY, ... separator has to be - (dash/hypen)
});
```